# Greatest $n$ such that $2^n \mid 63^{2018}-1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

> Find the greatest $n$ such that $2^n\mid 63^{2018}-1$

I got to this question and don't know how to solve it, I'm not familiar with questions in this type. I feel that we should get how many factors of $2$ we have in the $RHS$, so it would make it easier. I thought too in:

$63^{2018}-1=\underbrace{(63^{1009}-1)}_x \underbrace{(63^{1009}+1)}_y \implies n=\nu_2(xy)=\nu_2(x)+\nu_2(y)$, where $\nu_p(a)$ is the p-adic valuation. But $x$ and $y$ are not looking good.

I would be glad for help.

Comment: On a whim, taking $63=64-1$, I see $(64-1)^{2018}-1=(2^{12}-2^7+1)^{1009}-1$, but I haven't gotten much further than that.

Comment: Perhaps a further step would be $(k2^7+1)^{1009}-1=\dots+k^22^{14}\binom{1009}2+1009k2^7$, but do you know if $2^8$ divides the original?

Comment: @abiessu By calculator **$2^8$ does not** divide it

Comment: @JohnOmielan thanks, I will correct it for now on.

Comment: Follows immediately by LTE as in the linked dupes. This is the *master theorem* for problems like this so one should learn it asap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in [abiessu's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4475084/greatest-n-such-that-2n-mid-632018-1#comment9381282_4475084), note that $63 = 64 - 1$. Thus, using what you did with modulo $64$ gives that

$$x = 63^{1009}-1 \equiv (-1)^{1009} - 1 \equiv -2 \equiv 62 \pmod{64} \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Thus, $\nu_2(x) = 1$. Next, we have

$$y = 63^{1009} + 1 = (63 + 1)(\color{blue}{63^{1008} - 63^{1007} + \ldots - 63 + 1}) \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Note each term in $\color{blue}{\text{blue}}$ is odd, and that there are $1009$ (which is an odd #) of them, so their sum would also be odd. This means that $\nu_2(y) = \nu_2(63 + 1) = 6$. Altogether, we therefore get

$$n = \nu_2(x) + \nu_2(y) = 1 + 6 = 7 \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

---

Update: As indicated in [Jyrki's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4475084/greatest-n-such-that-2n-mid-632018-1/4475091#comment9381318_4475091), the [Lifting-the-exponent lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifting-the-exponent_lemma) could have been used instead to get that $\nu_2(x) = \nu_2(63-1) = 1$ and $\nu_2(y) = \nu_2(63+1) = 6$. Actually, I could've used that lemma with the original expression to more directly get $\nu_2(63^{2018} - 1) = \nu_2(63-1) + \nu_2(63+1) + \nu_2(2018) - 1 = 1 + 6 + 1 - 1 = 7$.

Comment: Wow, $(2)$ is clever. By the way, does this factorization have a "name"? Thank you for the help!

Comment: @IanBarquette You're welcome for the help. Regarding there being a specific name for the factorization, i.e., where for odd positive integer $m$ we have $x^m + y^m = (x + y)(x^{m-1} - x^{m-2}y \ldots - xy^{m-2} + y^{m-1})$, I don't know of any.

Comment: @IanBarquette I think that [lifting the exponent lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lifting-the-exponent_lemma) is the most general umbrella idea. At least one of them. +1, of course.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks for mentioning that. I forgot about that lemma when I wrote the answer, but I could have used it instead to get both $\nu_2(x)$ and $\nu_2(y)$. I've added an update to my answer about this.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Comment: @BillDubuque I'm aware of that site policy announcement. Note I suspected this was a duplicate and searched for an appropriate question to use to vote to close as a duplicate, but I couldn't find anything, with this likely being because I was checking just for the specific problem of $2^n\mid 63^{2018}-1$.

Comment: @John Searching via SE for `lifting exponent` yields 200 matches, including the linked dupes (and some of your answers using LTE).

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach:

$\underline{\text{Lemma 1}}$ 
$4 \mid 63^n - 1 \iff 4 \mid 63^{n+2} - 1.$ 
$4 \mid 63^n + 1 \iff 4 \mid 63^{n+2} + 1.$ 
**Proof**
For both assertions, it is sufficient to show that 
$~\displaystyle 4 \mid \left(63^2 - 1\right) = 4 \times 992.$

$\underline{\text{Lemma 2}}$ 
$64 \mid 63^n + 1 \iff 64 \mid 63^{n+4} + 1.$ 
$128 \mid 63^n + 1 \iff 128 \mid 63^{n+4} + 1.$ 
**Proof**
For both assertions, it is sufficient to show that 
$~\displaystyle 128 \mid \left(63^4 - 1\right) = 128 \times 123070.$

---

Let $A = 63^{1009} - 1, ~B = 63^{1009} + 1 \implies A \times B = 63^{2018} - 1.$

$2 \mid A.$ 
By Lemma 1, since $4 ~\nmid (63^1 - 1), ~4 ~\nmid ~(63^{1009} -1).$

$64 \mid (63^1 + 1)$ and $128 \nmid (63^1 + 1).$ 
Therefore, by Lemma 2, $~64 \mid B~$ and $~128 \nmid B.$

Therefore,

- the largest exponent $~\alpha~$ such that $~2^\alpha \mid A~$ is $~\alpha = 1.$
- the largest exponent $~\beta~$ such that $~2^\beta \mid B~$ is $~\beta = 6.$

Therefore,

$$2^7 | (A \times B) = 63^{2018} - 1, ~~\text{and}~~
2^8 \nmid (A \times B).$$